# WaveMediaStreamSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, wavmss

I found out a code on the net that plays a .wav file in C#. The code is as follows

```
private void btn_Play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog().Value)
            {
                Stream s = ofd.File.OpenRead();
                WaveMediaStreamSource wavMss = new WaveMediaStreamSource(s);
                try
                {
                    ME_Wav.SetSource(wavMss);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    // This file is not valid
                }
            }
        }
```

But the error occurs " the type or namespace "WaveMediaStreamSource" could not be found".
What is the namespace under which this is defined?

A very basic question it might be but I am just a beginer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Link](http://code.google.com/p/emagine/source/browse/trunk/EmagineClient/WavMss/WaveMediaStreamSource.cs?r=17) seems to define what your looking for. It looks like a custom class to me.

And [here](https://ziderengine.svn.codeplex.com/svn/ExEn/ExEnSilver/WavMSS/WaveMediaStreamSource.cs) is the class...